# Can you prevent Facebook apps from accessing your photo albums?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have built a Facebook application that requests permissions to access your photos when you allow that application access to your data.

In the majority of cases, I can then list the logged-in users photo albums, using the Graph API. However, various people are unable to see a list of their albums - the Graph API is returning an empty list, even though they actually have numerous albums visible (either publicly, or to friends only).

I've spent a while looking through the privacy settings, and can't see anything that would allow you to hide photos and albums from applications while keeping them visible on Facebook itself (and would find this strange anyway, since you've explicity allowed the application access to your photos and albums).

So... is there a way to prevent Facebook applications (specifically, the Graph API) from accessing your photos and albums?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and then I self-found out the reason: *it's due to the permission of that user which set in*

Follow these steps to resolve the problem:

- Privacy Settings
- Ads, Apps and Websites
- How people bring your info to apps they use

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think NO. If an API (or app) requires photos and albums and depends on them, it probably won't run without them. There are 2 ways:

1. Don't use that API/app; try to find another similar API;
2. Delete your pictures, if you like that API more than your photos.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. The app *does* depend on photos and albums, and it runs just fine, it just doesn't have access to then photos and albums, even though the user has explicitly granted the app access to them. My question is whether, even when granting such access, can you somehow prevent that app from accessing your photos and albums?